# Latex : incorrect nameref when custom counter is used in section name

Tags: latex

When a section name is based on a custom counter (with  `\newcounter`), the `\nameref` text is not the good one.

Below a simple example :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{hidelinks,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue}

\begin{document}
    \newcounter{my.counter}

\section{Section \arabic{my.counter}}
    \label{sct\arabic{my.counter}}
    Content of section \arabic{my.counter}.
    \begin{verbatim}
        \nameref{sct1}
    \end{verbatim}
    \nameref{sct1}

\stepcounter{my.counter}
\section{Section \arabic{my.counter}}\label{sct\arabic{my.counter}}
    \begin{verbatim}
        \nameref{sct0}
    \end{verbatim}
    \nameref{sct0}.

\end{document}
```

And the result is:

[image: example of improper PDF]

This example was compiled on overleaf to avoid "configuration" issue .

Answer (score 0):

You can ensure that your title will get expanded by using `\GetTitleStringSetup{expand}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{hidelinks,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue}


\GetTitleStringSetup{expand}

\begin{document}
    \newcounter{my.counter}

\section{Section \arabic{my.counter}}
    \label{sct\arabic{my.counter}}
    Content of section \arabic{my.counter}.
    \begin{verbatim}
        \nameref{sct1}
    \end{verbatim}
    \nameref{sct1}

\stepcounter{my.counter}
\section{Section \arabic{my.counter}}\label{sct\arabic{my.counter}}
    \begin{verbatim}
        \nameref{sct0}
    \end{verbatim}
    \nameref{sct0}.

\end{document}
```

[image]